# How long can I leave a Twilio Programmable voice web browser softphone client open and connected?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm using the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for JavaScript.
I've got a nice little softphone in a web browser based client.

How long does a web browser based client last by default?
Is there a default idle timeout for a connected voice client in a web browser?
Is there somewhere to change it's idle time?
is there a method like "on.disconnect" that we can use to display a "disconnected" indicator in the browser window?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using flex or a dialer like in this guide? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-dialer/node-angular

Comment: I'm using serverless.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/get-started#information

Answer (score 0):

I remembered a piece of ancient knowledge from a solution I built in the long long ago.

When you're minting a voice access token, you can set a TTL, like this:

```
const accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY, API_SECRET, {ttl: 36000})
```

the value of ttl is in seconds.  I think you can go 24 hours, but testing that would be arduous.